# Are the JavaFX 2 Gesture events automatically generated from TouchEvent or MouseEvent?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using a Macbook, which has a multitouch trackpad.Then I program a multitouch application with simple a scene and an ellipse called oval. I just have the following methods. And the zoom and rotate events are fired automatically when I perform a two finger action on the oval with my trackpad.

```
 oval.setOnZoom(new EventHandler<ZoomEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ZoomEvent event) {
                oval.setScaleX(oval.getScaleX() * event.getZoomFactor());
                oval.setScaleY(oval.getScaleY() * event.getZoomFactor());
                log("Ellipse: Zoom event" +
                        ", inertia: " + event.isInertia() + 
                        ", direct: " + event.isDirect());
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        oval.setOnRotate(new EventHandler<RotateEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(RotateEvent event) {
                oval.setRotate(oval.getRotate() + event.getAngle());
                log("Ellipse: Rotate event" +
                        ", inertia: " + event.isInertia() + 
                        ", direct: " + event.isDirect());
                event.consume();
            }
        });
```

However, I then wrote another JavaFX program to generate TouchEvent by my own (From multiple mice connected to a single computer with ManyMice library for java. I converted Multiple mice event to TouchEvent). The UI again has the same oval on an empty scene. This time, nothing happened when I use two mice to pan and rotate the oval.

I then tested with oval.SetOnTouchPressed and oval.SetOnTouchReleased to see if the oval has really received the touch event. And YES!! It does! So it means the oval receives touch event, but these "artificial" touch events are not automatically generating Gesture events like the Macbook Trackpad.

Do I need to write my own logic to generate Gesture events from TouchEvents, or there exists some methods to allow this happened automatically?